# Groovy/Scala - Abort Early while iterating using an accumulator

Tags: scala, groovy, functional-programming

I have a fairly large collection that I would like to iterate and find out if the collection contains more than one instance of a particular number. Since the collection is large, i'd like to exit early, i.e not traverse the complete list.

I have a dirty looking piece of code that does this in a non-functional programming way. However, i'm unable to find a functional programming way of doing this (In Groovy or Scala), since I need to do 2 things at the same time.

1. Accumulate state
2. Exit Early

The "accumulate state" can be done using the "inject" or "fold" methods in Groovy/Scala but there's no way of exiting early from those methods. Original groovy code is below. Any thoughts?

```
def collection = [1,2,3,2,4,6,0,65,... 1 million more numbers]
def n = 2

boolean foundMoreThanOnce(List<Integer> collection, Integer n) {
    def foundCount = 0
    for(Integer i : collection) {
        if(i == n) {
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
        }

        if(foundCount > 1) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false    
}

print foundMoreThanOnce(collection, n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible Scala solutions.

```
def foundMoreThanOnce[A](collection: Seq[A], target: A): Boolean =
  collection.dropWhile(_ != target).indexOf(target,1) > 0
```

Or a slight variation...

```
  collection.dropWhile(target.!=).drop(1).contains(target)
```

Scans the collection only until the 2nd target element is found.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about groovy, but if possible for you to use Java 8 then there is a possibility

```
collection.stream().filter(z -> {return z ==2;} ).limit(2)
```

the limit will stop the stream processing as soon as it get 2nd occurrence of 2.

You can use it as below, to ensure there are exact two occurrences

```
Long occ = collection.stream().filter(z -> {return z ==2;} ).limit(2).count();

if(occ == 2)
    return true;
```